# Why :first-child selector not working on div?

Tags: html, css

I am selecting specific divs with the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo selectors but `:first-child` is not working in any browser I have checked it in.

I've checked caniuse.com and css-tricks.com and the consensus is that `:first-child` is pretty widely supported so I'm thinking maybe there is some bug I am not aware of. I am running the app on a local node server. I have validated both my css and my html. Is anyone aware of any bugs that might prevent `:first-child` from working?

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 blurbs">
 <label>NEWS</label>
 <div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor spernatur aut odit aut fugit conse oluptate</p>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
  <a class="pull-left">RSS</a>
  <a class="pull-right">MORE NEWS</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

(not working)

```
.news .blurbs div:first-child{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    height: 260px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

(working)

```
.news .blurbs div:last-child{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: I dont see the element with class `news`

Comment: the element with class news is missing

Comment: .news can be disregarded. It's on a higher level element. I just edited the original post because I realized that :last-child is actually working. Only :first-child is not working.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes select the element that is the first/last child of the parent, filtered by any other chained selector, so `div:first-child` does not actually match anything as the first child within `.blurbs` is not a `div`.

What you need to use to get the effect you are after is the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class like this:

```
.news .blurbs div:first-of-type{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    height: 260px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8PaNE/)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the explanation. I did not know (obviously) that anything selected with :first-child needs to be an immediate child of the parent. I thought it would select the first child of its kind (in my case div). So yes, first-of-type is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's really surprising for me to know. Also, how does ````last-child```` work then? Why does it get the (unexpected) job done unlike ````first-child````?

Comment: @Sapinder depends on the HTML you are using. If you are looking at the above examples, `div:last-child` will work because the last direct child of `.blurbs` is a div.